# Want to know the Logic behind the code simple code

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, boolean

##### Given n boolean variables X1, X2, ..., and Xn, we wish to print all possible combinations of truth values they can assume. For instance, if n = 2, there are four possibilities: true, true; true, false; false, true; and false, false. Write a Java program in both iterative and recursive way to accomplish this.

Above one was the Question.

I was able to figure out an Recursive way but coming up with iterative way was a Hassle. ChatGPT gave me an Snippet.

```
import java.util.*;

public class IterativeCombinationWithoutBitManipulation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 2; // Number of boolean variables
    
    int totalCombinations = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCombinations; i++) {
        int temp = i;
        boolean[] values = new boolean[n];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            values[j] = temp % 2 == 1;
            temp /= 2;
        }
        
        for (boolean value : values) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Here I want to know what is happening in the second for loop? The modulo and the division are informed to be doing some kind of Binary conversion of Digits and converting to Boolean it seems when enquiring further in prompts. I further want to know why the value of *'i'* was chosen as value for the *'temp'* variable.

This will help me to migrate the logic to different types of problems while solving them. THANKS!

Comment: Why don't you ask it to explain?

Comment: This is a classic technique, every value from 0 to 2^n (exclusive) directly corresponds to a combination of true/false that the flags can have. This code loops over those numbers and converts them to the corresponding true/false combinations. If not using `i` there, what else would you use?

Comment: @harold I wonder what are some real use cases of this technique? only asking out of curiosity

Comment: @01000001 as far as I know it's mostly used to iterate through all the possible combinations of items from an array (then instead of outputting the true/false, that boolean is used to decide whether to take the j'th item of the array or not)

Comment: @harold Could you explain a bit more how  every value from 0 to 2^n (exclusive) directly corresponds to a combination of true/false that the flags can have. A detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Similarly, if you wanted to generate every possible 6-digit PIN code, that would just be the numbers 0 to 10^6 (exclusive). That's with 10 options per digit. In this case we have two options per digit (true and false) so we use binary.

Comment: @harold and in case of 3-digit PIN, the specific logic in question becomes values[j] = temp % 10; temp /= 10; (given we have 10 choices), which gives me 000,100.....899, 999... thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Using `i` as a loop variable is a hangover from FORTRAN, back in the days when you had to punch out your program on punch cards, and get the result back the next day.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to know what is happening in the second for loop? The modulo and the division are informed to be doing some kind of Binary conversion of Digits and converting to Boolean it seems when enquiring further in prompts. ..."*

If I understand correctly, I believe you're misinterpreting the syntax.

There's no conversion, `temp % 2 == 1` is a complete *[statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)*, in *Java*.

It's a less explicit way of writing the following.

```java
int x = temp % 2;
if (x == 1) {
    values[j] = true;
} else {
    values[j] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> print all possible combinations of truth values they can assume

This is just how binary works. So it's essentially asking, "Print every binary number from 0-N where 0 is False, and 1 is True

Okay, let's go line by line

```
int totalCombinations = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
```

This is true by definition. The max number you can represent in binary with n digits is 2^n-1. When you add zero as an option, the number of different numbers becomes 2^n. Think, with 2 digits:

00,01,10,11 -> 0,1,2,3 -> 4 options

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalCombinations; i++) {
```

We know we are going to have to print `totalCombination` times.

```
  int temp = i;
  boolean[] values = new boolean[n];
```

Create a copy of i because we're going to change it later & create a place to store our array of booleans (the binary number)

```
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    values[j] = temp % 2 == 1;
    temp /= 2;
  }
```

This is a little more complex than what we've dealt with so far. This for loop essentially turns `temp` into a binary number and stores each of the 1's and 0's as trues and falses in `values`

```
  for (boolean value : values) {
    System.out.print(value + " ");
  }
```

Print each of the booleans

```
  System.out.println();
```

New line.

Comment: Instead of the program walkthrough could you walk me through the complex part of how the temp is converted to a binary number and stores each of 1's and 0's as true and false.